# Windsor castle injecting dependency in nested classes with root interface resolved at runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a series of classes and interfaces for which I use dependency injection. The problem is that the "root" interface is resolved at runtime. Therefore I don't know how to use Windsor Castle to inject dependencies for interfaces "higher" in the hierarchy.

Here's an example:

```
public interface IConnectionSettings
{
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}

public class TestEnvironmentConnectionSettings
{
    string ConnectionString { get; }

    public TestEnvironmentConnectionSettings(EEnvironment environment)
    {
        ConnectionString = "ConnectionStringTo" + environment;
    }
}

public interface IDatabaseConnection
{
    IEnumerable<T> RunQuery<T>(string query);
}

public class DatabaseConnection : IDatabaseConnection
{
    private readonly IConnectionSettings _connectionSettings;

    public DatabaseConnection(IConnectionSettings connectionSettings)
    {
        _connectionSettings = connectionSettings;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> RunQuery<T>(string query)
    {
        // do something and return results
    }
}

public interface IPersonConnection
{
    Person GetPerson(int id);
}

public class PersonConnection : IPersonConnection
{
    private readonly IDatabaseConnection _databaseConnection;

    public PersonConnection(IDatabaseConnection databaseConnection)
    {
        _databaseConnection = databaseConnection;
    }

    public GetPerson(int id)
    {
        // prepare query and return results
    }
}
```

The problem is I would like to get an instance of PersonConnection once I know which EEnvironment I will use. But now I have to construct TestEnvironmentConnectionSettings to get DatabaseConnection and to get PersonConnection etc. Can Windor Castle help me do this so I don't have to create a factory? Or is my code incorrectly designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide the `EEnvironment` to the constructor directly and instead provide an interface than can provide the `EEnvironment` (from config, database, whatever), and register all components using the appropriate non-singleton lifestyle (transient, scoped, etc) then when you resolve a `PersonConnection` from the Castle Windsor container the dependencies will also be resolved and the appropriate database connection established.

Comment: I could do that, but the requirements are that EEnvironment will change at the runtime. Specifically, the user will be able to change the environment from GUI using checkboxes. Do you think it would be okay to have a separate class that would look at the checkbox and return current environment? Thank you.

Comment: The point is, that you define an interface that provides an `EEnvironent`, `IEnvironmentProvider` for example, it doesn't matter if the implementation of that interface is linked to a checkbox or a database or some config.